# Building GDAL With MinGW (using Windows-32bit)

Tags: c, mingw, gdal

i am new to GDAL.

=> I want to build GDAL from source using MinGW for windows to get libgdal-1.dll, libgdal-1.dll.a. 
=> I follow the instruction given on the GDAL website https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingWithMinGW

=> i install the MinGW and using msys.bat i configure the GDAL source using ./configure command. but when i give the make command it gives me
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ttY9.png)
`make[1]: *** [cpl_xml_validate.lo] Error1
make[1]: Leaving directory /c/MinGW/gdal-2.2.4/port'
make: *** [port-target] Error 2.`

Please help me in solving this problem.

i am thankful to all of you for your precious time and positive feedback.

Comment: The error refers to libxml. Did you have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984853/mingw-libxml2-issue)?